# Make TextArea fill the top of the Screen and IFrame fill bottom

Tags: html, css

I am making a HTML Editor in electron and I want my textarea that I write the HTML in to be at the top of the screen and my IFrame that shows my HTML as a page at the bottom, also both of those need to fit exactly half of the screen each. This is what I have came with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>HTML Editor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
    <iframe id="view"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can probably understand it doesn't really fit as I want it, I would really appreciate getting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#editor {height: 50vh; width: 100%;}
#view {height: 50vh; width: 100%;}
```

```html
<textarea id="editor">your text</textarea>
    <iframe id="view"></iframe>
```

Use this, if need any change please let me know